# mkdir function, doesn't appear to be working

Tags: php, mysql, mkdir

I have created a mkdir function in my php webpage but it doesn't appear to be working.

Here it is:

```
mkdir("Game/" . $user . "/" . $name . ".actibuild", 0777, true);
```

user and name are defined above. Here's the snippet of code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['name'])){
        if (isset($_POST['desc'])){
            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
            $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
            $user = $check_user['Username'];
            mkdir("Game/" . $user . "/" . $name . ".actibuild", 0777, true);


            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `games`(`creator`, `name`, `desc`) VALUES ('$user', '$name', '$desc')");
            header('Location: Games.php');
        }
    }
```

It is correctly running those queries into the database, but it isn't creating those directories.

Can you help?

Comment: Any errors in the php error log? This is probably a permission issue ...

Comment: `mkdir()` will return `false` if it fails. Does it? Do you have file permissions to create directories in that location?

Comment: Yes, there are permissions for it to be created, and it doesn't seem to return false or true.

Comment: Note, it is very dangerous to use the user-provided POST values to modify your filesystem.  You must validate that they don't contain path poisoning characters like `../` or a NULL byte to prevent writing to unintended areas of your FS.

Comment: @MrSlayer the OP has already set the recursive option to true.

Comment: @user1380580 Of course it won't show what it returns how you have it. Try something like `if (mkdir(...)) /* worked */ else /* didn't */`

Comment: @MrSlayer as far as I know, the recursive parameter is true.

Answer (score 0):

check the current directory with:

`echo __FILE__;`

or

`echo getcwd();`

and build your path relative to this reference.

or

you can use chdir("/") to set the root directory as the current directory, then try to create your path.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help me with this. I've done it, but hasn't given me any progress.

Comment: Oh BTW your root directory isn't "/", it is "/Idk". Write `chdir("/Idk");` before mkdir and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You using relative paths, it may be not the place you think directories are created but current directory/web-root/etc.

Try:

```
$path = "Game/" . $user . "/" . $name . ".actibuild";
is_writable('.') || die(realpath('.') . ' is not writable');
mkdir($path, 0777, true) || die(realpath($path).' directory not created');
print_r(realpath($path));
```

Comment: I'm getting 'Directory not created' with that.

Comment: Can you run the same php from the command line, and see what happens then? It'll at least let you know if there's a problem with the command you're running, or with PHP's permissions.

Comment: Command Line? Sorry, I've no idea what that is, I'm relatively new to PHP.

Comment: @user1380580, Then `is_writable('.') || die(realpath('.'). ' is not writable');` should tell you if it's permissions case...

Comment: I'm getting: 

Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in C:\xampp\htdocs\Idk\My\Games.php on line 40
Directory not created

Comment: It's means that directory is already created and exists at location that can be discovered by `realpath($path)`

Comment: I see, because 'Game' already exists, as I wanted. But I wanted to create the directory inside the Game folder, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where PHP executes? You have a relative system path (starting with Game). Chances are, your directory *is* getting created (if permissions allow), but in a location relative to the working directory, which is not necessarily the same place where your PHP script lives.

Comment: It executes from localhost, using xampp. The path to the file is: C:\xampp\htdocs\Idk